# How can I use jQuery for a specific field in odoo v10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, odoo, odoo-10

I am new to odoo. So i want to write code in Add product there is 3 Fields `carton box weight` , `no of product in carton` and `product box weight` (this products are packed in carton) based on this i want to remove the total product box weight from gross weight

For example i get products in carton box and weight of that box is 26 Kg

There is 25 product in one each carton box product is packed in separate box (here assume product box weight is 150 Gram) so i want to remove this product box weight from gross weight

```
carton box weight (custom field) = 26 kg
No of product in carton (custom field) = 25
product box weight(custom field) = 150 Gm

Gross Weight = (26kg - (25 X 150gm) ) = 22.250 Kg
```

i am doing this cause product selling price is based on weight in Kg and i have to remove the weight of box

so i am trying to implement this Logic. you can suggest me other way if it is possible. suggestion are welcome